# Appium simulator - fails to initialize on IOS 15, and XCODE 13

Tags: appium, appium-ios

Trying to start IOS iPhone 13 simulator on IOS 15 it keeps failing - these are my capabilities:

```json
{
"automationName": "XCUITest",
"platformName": "iOS",
"deviceName": "iPhone 13",
"platformVersion": "15.0"
}
```

running on Xcode 13

getting the following error:

```
[XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session (An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8100). Retrying...
```

does Appium support Xcode 13?
am I missing anything here?